# No output when running TensorFlow code on Cloud Machine Learning Engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

When I run the following in terminal:

```
$MODEL_DIR=output
gcloud ml-engine local train     --module-name trainer.task     --package-path trainer/     --job-dir $MODEL_DIR
```

It runs successfully but I don't get anything in the output folder. Although according to this I should see some files and checkpoints: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction

In the code I've got this line to save my model:

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./my_mnist_model.ckpt")
```

That generates following files in the active directory: `my_mnist_model.ckpt.index`, `my_mnist_model.ckpt.meta`, `my_mnist_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`

However they are not in `output` folder. And when I run it on the Cloud Machine Learning Engine I don't get anything in the specified output folder in my bucket either.

So the model is successfully trained but not saved anywhere.

What am I missing in my code / gcloud command?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out myself that i need to handle --job-dir myself in the script. From the getting started manual i thought it is handled by gcloud command that runs training.

Comment: When you specify the location to save the model inside your code,  you are doing that for a local execution. If you want to deploy your model to the Google Cloud Platform, there is no necessity to specify any output folders in the code since you will be specifying the output  by passing it as the job-dir argument. You can look at the task.py file in the trainer folder of the getting started example from Google Cloud to see that the job-dir argument is parsed as an input and then used to specify the model directory for the output.

Comment: This seems to directly conflict with the solution that worked for @user912830823. So, which is it?